# Can Elasticsearch stream the SearchResponse?

Tags: java, performance, elasticsearch, stream, inputstream

I have a rest application that can export some report data from Elasticsearch. It is easy to do with the Java API:

```
SearchResponse response = getClient()
            .prepareSearch("my_index_name")
            .setQuery(QueryBuilders.someQuery())
            .addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.someAggregation())
            .get();
```

The problem starts with the big responses. Using this code snippet, the response is read to build the `SearchResponse` object in memory. In my case, the response **does not fits in memory**.

Paging cannot help because we often need to return the full data and Aggregations [do not support paging yet](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/4915).

I know that I can use the Elasticsearch REST API to read the response as stream, but manually build the request it is cumbersome. I really want something like this:

```
// my dream API
InputStream response = getClient()
            .prepareSearch("my_index_name")
            .setQuery(QueryBuilders.someQuery())
            .addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.someAggregation())
            .getStream();
```

So, can the Elasticsearch Java API stream the `SearchResponse`?

Answer (score 2):

A [proposal for streaming results](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/12188) does exist but it doesn't seem to have picked up steam so far and was closed (for now).

There's a way to do it with [`XContentBuilder`](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Streaming-a-whole-SearchResponse-as-JSON-td2128594.html) but that still requires the whole response to be in memory before being sent.

It might not be what you want, but that's the closest thing that I know which could fulfill your need. Worth giving it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no way to obtain an `InputStream` from the Java API (but I might be wrong). I also think there is no way to directly obtain an `InputStream` in [Jest](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest) (a REST-based Elasticsearch Java API).

You mention that it is cumbersome to create the search request to the `_search` endpoint yourself: if you're referring to building the actual json query, I just would like to point out that once you have a `SearchSourceBuilder`, you can call `toString()` on it to get a fully working json representation of your query.

```
    SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
    sourceBuilder.query(this.getQuery())
            .from(this.getFrom())
            .size(this.getSize())
            .fetchSource(this.getSource(), null);
    this.getSort().forEach(sourceBuilder::sort);
    sourceBuilder.toString() // the json representation
```